# Forced deletion of Pod on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How do you **hard** force a pod to terminate?

We have tried every documented form of kubectl delete pod and they remain. kubectl reports that they've been deleted, but kubectl get pods tells a different story. All pods that they could've been using have been deleted as well as any pods that could be using them.

Is there any form of kubectl SERIOUSLY_DELETE this pod?

I've tried: `kubectl delete pods --all  --grace-period=0 --force -n monitoring`

With no favorable result.  I've also tried to delete them individually.

`NAME                        READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
es-master-962148878-7vxpp   1/1       Terminating   1          12d
es-master-962148878-h1r4k   1/1       Terminating   1          12d
es-master-962148878-rkg9g   1/1       Terminating   1          12d`

Answer (score 1):

Taken from `kubectl delete --help`:

```
kubectl delete pod foo --grace-period=0 --force
```

Note that if your pods are controlled via e.g. a deployment, then a new one will be recreated every time you delete one.  So do make sure that's not the symptom you're observing!

Comment: Note that if you've already tried this and it doesn't help, it would be helpful to update your question to include the specific console output you're seeing.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include this?  (It's really hard to parse here.)

Comment: FWIW, this may be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453792/pods-stuck-at-terminated-status