# Kubernetes Pods Not Being Evicted

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have multiple pods on Kubernetes (v1.23.5) that are not being evicted and rescheduled in case of node failure.

According to Kubernetes documentation, this process must begin after 300s:

> Kubernetes automatically adds a Toleration for `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready` and `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable` with `tolerationSeconds=300` unless you, or a controller, set those tolerations explicitly.
> These automatically-added tolerations mean that Pods remain bound to Nodes for 5 minutes after detecting one of these problems.

Unfortunately, pods get stuck in terminating status and would not evict. However, in one test on a pod without any PVC attached, it evicted and started running on another node.

- I'm trying to understand how I can make other pods evict after the default 300s time.
- I don't know why it would not happen automatically, and I must drain the pod stuck in a terminating state to make it work properly.

### Update

I have seen the [kvaps/kube-fencing](https://github.com/kvaps/kube-fencing/blob/master/deploy/kube-fencing.yaml#L128) project. There seems to be a fencing procedure that runs in case of a node failure. I couldn't make it solve my problem, and I didn't. I don't know whether it is because of my lack of comprehension of this project, or it is solely used to handle the node in case of a failure and not the pods stuck in termination state and evicting those pods.

Comment: Is this other question and its answers useful for helping you to solve your issue? [Pods stuck in Terminating status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453792/pods-stuck-in-terminating-status)

Comment: Thank you! I've seen that before, but the thing is I'm trying to understand how I can configure this to be evicted automatically.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue?

Comment: Not yet, but there seems to be a problem with ceph-csi not detaching volumes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this problem.

First one is to use [kvaps/kube-fencing](https://github.com/kvaps/kube-fencing). You need to configure a PodTemplate in which you can set a node to be deleted from the cluster when it becomes `NotReady` or flush the node. If you have volumes attached to the pod, the pods will remain in the `ContainerCreating` state.

There are the annotations in the PodTemplate:

```
annotations:
  fencing/mode: 'delete'
  fencing/mode: 'flush'
```

The second way is to use the Kubernetes [Non-Graceful Node Shutdown](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/05/20/kubernetes-1-24-non-graceful-node-shutdown-alpha/). This is not available in Kubernetes (v1.23.5) and you have to upgrade.